# Is there a git style amend option in TFVC?

Tags: git, tfs, commit, tfvc

In git there is a very handy feature that lets you fix your last commit, e.g. when you have forgotten something that does not justify a full commit.

It is very easy to do this in git:

```
git commit --amend
```

That way you don't have to specify a commit message or anything else, the commit is simply "appended" to your last full commit - or at least that is how I understand it.

Is there anything similar available in TFVC?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

No, not really. You can update the Check-in comment, or associate a work item, but you cannot change the file contents of the check-in. A rollback doesn't help either, since that will add yet an additional compensating checkin to the history, making it even harder to understand.

To update the message, open the TFVC history panel and right click a changeset. Choose <kbd>Show Changeset Details</kbd> and you'll be able to update the Check-in comment and optionally the check-in notes.

To associate to a new work item make note of the changeset number, open the work item and go to the links tab. Click add-link and chose the link type "Changeset", supply the number and save the work item.

Comment: Seems what TFS offers as "git" is, ahhh, limited, in "minute, subtle, and utterly effective" ways.

Comment: @jthill, when using Git on TFS, you have Amend support. But when using TFVC you don't.